# phpmyadmin fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to do the next query:

```
SELECT 
    docs_sam.id as id_doc, 
    docs_sam.title as nom_doc, 
    docs_sam.author as autor, 
    docs_sam.status as estat_doc, 
    docs_sam.sent as sent, 
    docs_sam.cdate as data,                 
    main_clients.name as nomClient
FROM
    main_clients INNER JOIN docs_sam
    ON main_clients.id = docs_sam.clientid
ORDER BY docs_sam.cdate DESC;
```

when the phpmyadmin crashes and show the next error:

**Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in **/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php** on line **101**

I have an app mounted onto a database that works onto the system,
but now every time I try to start 'phpmyadmin' shows this error.

If I do an unset of $_COOKIE in the code of phpmyadmin it works one time, but when I try to do something the system crashes again.
Sorry for my english, and thanks

Answer (score 6):

I used this way, it solved my problem, when I import file with format .sql.zip.

Go to

> C:\Wamp\bin\apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini

Then set

> memory_limit = -1

See [more](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Pzvhg52keabfbt3l) to clear problem.

Comment: OP uses Linux obviously

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that query.  The result set is too large ;)

Actually, that's what, 134MB?  You'll need to check with the server administrator to see if they will allow PHP to use that much memory.

If you *are* the server administrator (and you do have enough RAM to do this), you can adjust the value of "memory_limit" in php.ini to a value larger than 128MB.

Answer (score 0):

To query large datasets in phpMyAdmin, the best practice is to limit the resultset and allow phpMyAdmin to use pagination.

**Don't** do changes to the memory limit, it does not solve the problem, only allows the problem to get bigger.

```
SELECT 
    docs_sam.id as id_doc, 
    docs_sam.title as nom_doc, 
    docs_sam.author as autor, 
    docs_sam.status as estat_doc, 
    docs_sam.sent as sent, 
    docs_sam.cdate as data,                 
    main_clients.name as nomClient
FROM
    main_clients INNER JOIN docs_sam
    ON main_clients.id = docs_sam.clientid
ORDER BY docs_sam.cdate DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```